# how to delete the end of "}" and append three rows contents

Tags: r

a.txt contents:

```
{\aaa
{\bbb\ccc}
{\aaa
\bbb
\ccc
}

}
```

I can load my text in R using readLines (or scan). I want to know how to delete the end of "}" and append three rows contents:

```
\ddd
\eee
\fff
```

then save new file.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you just want to add those new lines into the main block. If that's the case, something like

```
lines<-scan(what=character(), text="{\\aaa
{\\bbb\\ccc}
{\\aaa
\\bbb
\\ccc
}

}
")
morelines<-append(lines, c("\\ddd","\\eee","\\fff"), after=length(lines)-1)
writeLines(morelines, "out.txt")
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you! If I want to delete the end of "}" firstly,then append.How to do it?

Comment: In this case `lines` is just like any other vector in R. The easiest way to remove it would be to use negative indexing or the `head` function.

Comment: In fact, i probably should have called it something other than `lines` since that's the name of a base plotting function, but oh well.

Comment: I use readlins function and results were 7 character.How to read a.txt as 1 character